# Nginx configuration to Allow curl to Lotstash HTTP Plugin

Tags: nginx, logstash, elk, certbot

I have Logstash 8.0.1 with the HTTP plugin running behind an Nginx Reverse Proxy. In addition, I have already used Let's Encrypt Certbot to provide a certificate. I want to be able to do something like the following to push data to Logstash via curl command:

```
curl --user elastic:<username> -XPUT https://elastic.example.com:8080/_doc/dat/5  -d 'hello'
```

I have nginx configured in the following way:

```
http {
    server {
       server_name elastic.example.com;
       location / {
         proxy_pass https://10.6.101.20:8080;
       }

   listen 8080 ssl; # managed by Certbot
   ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/elastic.example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
   ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/elastic.example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
   include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
   ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
```

}

I get a "port 8080 failed: Connection refused"

I suspect the problem can be found in the "location /" line, but I don't know how to fix it. (Adding a similar block for :9200 to support Elasticsearch queries works great.)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out... I was running nginx within a Docker container and forgot to publish port 8080.  Ugh.  The good news, is that it works!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).